# Extjs numberfield issue

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am Using EXT-JS 3.x

In the number field, it's not accepting when i am trying to input 0.
i am using these following validation:

```
allowDecimals : false,

allowNegative : false,
```

But i need to be able to enter zero   (0)  into the number field.

Is by anyway these previous validation are hindering inputting zero?

What validation can i need to add that would also keep my already existing validations intact ?

Could anyone help me throw some light on this issue?

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as correct?  My rep sucks and I need all the points I can get!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put together a fiddle that shows it working with the options you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/c4mj7/

You probably have something else in the way.

```
var number = new Ext.form.NumberField({
    renderTo:'number',
    allowDecimals : false,
    allowNegative : false
});
```